# How to handle class function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I want to be able to use a member variable to hold the address a function to call

I got the error:

> cannot convert 'void (TestClass::*)(bool)' to 'void (*)(bool)' in
> assignment

TestClass.cpp

```
#include "TestClass.h"

TestClass::TestClass()
{
    _myFctPtr = &setFired;
}

void TestClass::setFired(bool isFired)
{
    _fired = isFired;
}

void TestClass::updateValue()
{
    (_myFctPtr)(true);
}


bool TestClass::getFired()
{
    return _fired;
}
```

TestClass.h

```
#pragma once
class TestClass
{
    private:
        bool _fired = false;

    protected:
        void (*_myFctPtr)(bool);

    public:
        TestClass();
        void setFired(bool);
        void updateValue();
        bool getFired();
};
```

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Answer (score 2):

The error:

> `cannot convert 'void (TestClass::*)(bool)' to 'void (*)(bool)' in assignment`

Is showing you that pointers to class member functions have a different type from regular function pointers. This is because, in addition to the regular function arguments and return type, these functions are differentiated by *the object they are called on* (i.e. their `this`), which must be provided when invoking them.

Specifically, for a pointer to a function on TestClass which accepts a `bool` argument as shown here, you need to to define your field as the type `void (TestClass::*)(bool)`:

```
void (TestClass::*_myFctPtr)(bool);
```

You can call this like so, assuming you want to invoke the method on `this`:

```
((this).*(_myFctPtr))(true);
```

[This article](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types) provides additional useful information and advice on better, cleaner ways to invoke pointers to member functions - e.g. using `std::invoke` for cleaner syntax than what I provided above - but this is the bare minimum to quickly solve your issue.

Comment: Thank your for your quiock answer it helped me find a solution !

Comment: @CharlesPlante remember to mark a correct solution!